# Using stl_tree.h on Android NDK results in "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

I'm porting a native library to a NDK application.

When I try to use the stl_tree.h #include, I got the following error.

```
error: stl_tree.h: No such file or directory
```

This is my Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -la -lb -lc -lstdc++ -lgcc #I try to explicit declare the stdc++ and gcc but still doesn't works.
LOCAL_MODULE    := rmsdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := curlnetprovider.cpp RMServices.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include-all \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/include-all/openssl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := adept cryptopenssl curl dp expat fonts hobbes jpeg mschema png t3 xml zlib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is my Application.mk

```
APP_MODULES := adept cryptopenssl curl dp expat fonts hobbes jpeg mschema png t3 xml zlib rmsdk
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

My actual problem is, when compiling I get a: '_Rb_tree_increment' is not a member of 'std'
This is why I try to include the stl_tree myself. It appears this lib don't get included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the stlport from NDK 5.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for C++, not for android, but why are you trying to include `stl_tree.h` directly? You should include either `<map>` or `<set>` to get the actual container you want to use. In g++ anyway `stl_tree.h` is just a private implementation used by `map` and `set`.

Comment: Actually, I'm just trying to discover why my application inst compiling. The problem was in the _Rb_tree_increment and I found it in the stl_tree.h file, this is why I'm including it. But even with <map> this function errors when compile "'_Rb_tree_increment' is not a member of 'std'". Ty.

Answer (score 0):

The Android NDK doesn't have the STL (or at least, it didn't the last time I looked at the SDK, which was on Froyo).

The reason why it doesn't have the STL is that by default everything is compiled with exceptions disabled. So be very, very careful when using third-party STL ports; there's a good chance that if anything goes wrong it'll just crash.

Comment: NDK5 offers the stlport and gnustl_static.